# Issue importing Xcode5-6 projects to another MacBook: Apple LLVM 6.0 Error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, llvm

I have several projects (iOS and MacOS) developed originally on Xcode5 and then I continued their development in Xcode6

this is the original MacBook Pro

[image]

and the description of the project running on Xcode6 (original MacBook Pro)

[image]

and this is the new MacBook Pro

[image]

and the project running on Xcode6
[image]

error description:
[image]

I even tried to look for the eAccounting-Prefix.pch file, as you can see there it is:
[image]

---

**EDIT:** new captures added

precompile prefix header path

[image]

however I found something here:
[image]

I deleted that file in red from there, clean, build and run, but I got the same result again...

I also tried uninstalling and re installing the project but nothing happened, this error happens with all my xCode projects (iOS and MacOS) developed on my first MacBook Pro, any help I'll appreciate

Comment: There is probably an issue in a path to a file, I believe your error says it looks for a path to /Users/OLD_MAC_USER/... You should look at your project's build settings and search for "path". Make sure there is no absolute reference to a file.

Comment: in fact KENNETH is the new MacUser... gonna updload a picture of that too